# Customize respond after h:ajax call

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have something like:

```
<h:commandButton>
     <h:ajax event="click" listener="#{controller.onLog}" onchange="onLogProcess" />
     ....
</h:commandButton>
```

I send a post to the server, do some stuff in the listener function. Then I would like to return a string / message (respond) to the client back and catch it with javascript in "onLogProcess" to show to the user a customize string.

I'm looking into it, but I haven't found anything yet...

Is there any way that I can do this with JSF?

I'm using JSF 2.1 / Mojarra 2.1.2

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `<f:ajax>` (not `<h:ajax>`!) conditionally render a `<h:outputScript>`.

```html
<h:commandButton action="#{controller.onLog}">
    <f:ajax render="script" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:panelGroup id="script">
    <h:outputScript rendered="#{not empty controller.log}">
        onLogProcess('#{controller.log}');
    </h:outputScript>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Where `#{controller.log}` is your string which you'd like to pass to the JS function. Make sure that it doesn't contain JS special characters like `'`, linebreaks, etc. Use if necessary Apache Commons Lang `StringEscapeUtils#escapeJavaScript()` for this.